# Unresolved symbols during cross compilation linking with Boost log

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi2

I'm cross compiling project with following toolset:

- cmake
- Toolchain is arm-linux-gnueabihf
- sysroot (which is actually rsync of necessary stuff from Raspberry Pi 2 and contains all of headers and libraries I need)
- and list of find_package

Boost configured in following manner:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CPU_FLAGS} "-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK -fPIC -std=gnu++14 ${CMAKE_ARCH}")
set(Boost_DEBUG              OFF)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS    OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED  ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
set(BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK       ON)   # force dynamic linking for all libraries
set(BOOST_COMPONENTS
    system
    thread
    program_options
    regex
    filesystem
    unit_test_framework
    date_time
    chrono
    log_setup
    log
    )
set(BOOST_ROOT ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/usr/inc)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf)
find_package(Boost 1.54.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${BOOST_COMPONENTS})
```

Under the OS X compilation and linking just goes fine and I'm able send application to the RPI2 and run it.

The problem is in linking process under Ubuntu. It unable to find couple of symbols related to boost.log:

```
logger/liblogger.a(logger.cpp.o): In function `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >& boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::formatted_write<wchar_t>(wchar_t const*, int)':
logger.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix24basic_formatting_ostreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE15formatted_writeIwEERS6_PKT_i[_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix24basic_formatting_ostreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE15formatted_writeIwEERS6_PKT_i]+0x76): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert(wchar_t const*, unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::locale const&)'
logger/liblogger.a(logger.cpp.o): In function `void boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::aligned_write<wchar_t>(wchar_t const*, int)':
logger.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix24basic_formatting_ostreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE13aligned_writeIwEEvPKT_i[_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix24basic_formatting_ostreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE13aligned_writeIwEEvPKT_i]+0x6c): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert(wchar_t const*, unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::locale const&)'
logger.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix24basic_formatting_ostreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE13aligned_writeIwEEvPKT_i[_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix24basic_formatting_ostreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE13aligned_writeIwEEvPKT_i]+0xc6): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert(wchar_t const*, unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::locale const&)'
logger/liblogger.a(logger.cpp.o): In function `void boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::feed_record<boost::mutex, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_ostream_backend<char> >(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::mutex&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_ostream_backend<char>&)':
logger.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix5sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE11feed_recordINS_5mutexENS2_26basic_text_ostream_backendIcEEEEvRKNS1_11record_viewERT_RT0_[_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix5sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE11feed_recordINS_5mutexENS2_26basic_text_ostream_backendIcEEEEvRKNS1_11record_viewERT_RT0_]+0xda): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_ostream_backend<char>::consume(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
logger/liblogger.a(logger.cpp.o): In function `void boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::feed_record<boost::mutex, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend>(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::mutex&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend&)':
logger.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix5sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE11feed_recordINS_5mutexENS2_17text_file_backendEEEvRKNS1_11record_viewERT_RT0_[_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix5sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE11feed_recordINS_5mutexENS2_17text_file_backendEEEvRKNS1_11record_viewERT_RT0_]+0xda): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::consume(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
logger/liblogger.a(logger.cpp.o): In function `void boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::feed_record<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::fake_mutex, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_ostream_backend<char> >(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::fake_mutex&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_ostream_backend<char>&)':
logger.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix5sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE11feed_recordINS1_3aux10fake_mutexENS2_26basic_text_ostream_backendIcEEEEvRKNS1_11record_viewERT_RT0_[_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix5sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE11feed_recordINS1_3aux10fake_mutexENS2_26basic_text_ostream_backendIcEEEEvRKNS1_11record_viewERT_RT0_]+0xda): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_ostream_backend<char>::consume(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
logger/liblogger.a(logger.cpp.o): In function `void boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::feed_record<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::fake_mutex, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend>(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::fake_mutex&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend&)':
logger.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix5sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE11feed_recordINS1_3aux10fake_mutexENS2_17text_file_backendEEEvRKNS1_11record_viewERT_RT0_[_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix5sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE11feed_recordINS1_3aux10fake_mutexENS2_17text_file_backendEEEvRKNS1_11record_viewERT_RT0_]+0xda): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::consume(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

with:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

seems all of libraries up there

```
/usr/local/gcc-linaro-5.1-2015.08-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++  --sysroot=/home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK -fPIC -std=gnu++14 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a7 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard  -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf CMakeFiles/hub.dir/main/main.cpp.o  -o hub  -L/home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf  -L/home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/lib  -L/home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib  -L/home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf  -L/home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5 -rdynamic sensor-framework/libsensor-framework.a transport-framework/libtransport-framework.a tools/libtools.a logger/liblogger.a database-connector/libdb-conn.a -lbluetooth /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsoci_core.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsoci_postgresql.so -lpq -lpthread /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_program_options.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_system.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_thread.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_regex.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_filesystem.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_unit_test_framework.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_date_time.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_chrono.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_log.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_log_setup.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.a /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgthread-2.0.so /home/amr/iot_hub/3rd-party/rpi2_sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgmodule-2.0.so sensor-framework/libsensor-framework.a -Wl,-rpath,/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5:
```

What can be root cause of that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found some workaround.
I use different toolchains on OS X (4.9) and Ubuntu (5.1) which seems produces some difference in linking process (or there is no binary compatibility). Installing linaro toolchain on Ubuntu with same version as OS X have fixed the issue.